# Hartshorne chapter IV Exercise 2.2(b)

Tags: algebraic-geometry

The exercise is stated as follows:

> (b) Given six distinct elements $\alpha_{1}, \ldots, \alpha_{6} \in k$, let $K$ be the extension of $k(x)$ determined by the equation $z^{2}=\left(x-\alpha_{1}\right) \cdots\left(x-\alpha_{6}\right)$. Let $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^{1}$ be the corresponding morphism of curves. Show that $g(X)=2$, the map $f$ is the same as the one determined by the canonical linear system, and $f$ is ramified over the six points $x=\alpha_{i}$ of $\mathbb{P}^{1}$, and nowhere else. (Cf. (II, Ex. 6.4).)

Use Hurwitz's formula I can easily prove all things but "f is the same as the one determined by the canonical linear system". So I need to prove $f^*(\mathcal O(1))=\omega_X$, but how? Could you provide some hints?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Here's a start: $f^*(\mathcal{O}(1))$ is a line bundle associated to some divisor $D$. What is $\deg D$? What is $l(D)$?

Comment: @HankScorpio Good point! I have solved it by your hint. Thanks a lot!